# Using VBA to insert formulas using multiple dynamic ranges

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

My macro currently brings in data and breaks the data up based on a certain column. Which splits everything into 4 sections - one on top of the other with a gap of 4 rows between each section.
These sections can be different sizes each time the file is run.
I now need to be able to put SUM formulas within the gaps between each section using VBA.
The current code i have isn't working how i want it too and i am probably going in the wrong direction. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[an extract of the data - there is always data within column A](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qib62.png)

```
Dim iFirst As String
Dim iLast As String
Dim iRange As Range

iFirst = Selection.End(xlUp).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 14).Address
iLast = Selection.End(xlUp).Offset(0, 14).Address

Set iRange = Range(iFirst & ":" & iLast)
ActiveCell = WorksheetFunction.Sum(iRange)
```

Comment: The thing you wrote is possible (anything is possible in excel world).  However, you can reach to a view similar to the one you described with a `pivot table`.

Comment: @OzgunSenyuva This isn't something that i can use a pivot table with.
I have a data set which has hundreds of thousands of transactions within it and this particular macro is then sending a request for a certain set of that data which then need to be bought and displayed as a reconciliation which has been in place for years. The reconciliation format cant be changed, I am just automating it.

Comment: I see.  Maybe you can add sum formulas within your macro which creates the 4 rows gaps.